# Caption sub-level within minipage

Tags: graphics, minipage, includegraphics

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{
    font=bf,
    size=normalsize,
    justification=centerlast,
    %labelsep=newline
    }
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\figurewidth}{0.95}
\newcommand{\figureheight}{0.375}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\figurewidth\linewidth, height=\figureheight\textheight]{frog.jpg}
        \caption{The first frog}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\figurewidth\linewidth, height=\figureheight\textheight]{frog.jpg}
        \caption{The second frog}
    \end{minipage}
        \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\figurewidth\linewidth, height=\figureheight\textheight]{frog.jpg}
        \caption{The third frog}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\figurewidth\linewidth, height=\figureheight\textheight]{frog.jpg}
        \caption{The fourth frog}
    \end{minipage}
    \vspace{2ex}
\caption{A couple of frogs}
\parbox{\linewidth}{\small\lipsum[1]\vspace{2ex}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which produces this output: [image: frogs]

I have two issues:

(i) Is is possible to add a small amount of vertical space between the top (Figure 1 and 2) and the bottom (Figure 3 and 4)?

(ii) Is it possible to create a sub-level within the minipage environment? Say the overall page/figure is labeled "Figure 5: A couple of frogs", then I would like to name the individual frogs something like: "Panel 5.A: The first frog", "Panel 5.B: The second frog", etc. In addition, I would like the individual picture caption (in this case the captions for figure 1, 2, 3 and 4) to be in a normal font instead of a bold font.

Comment: The subcaption package uses \subcaption to do what you want.  In also uses a subfigure environment which is basicially a minipage with subcaptions.  As for vertical spaces, you can also play with \abovecaptionskip and \belowcaptionskip (lengths).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Mr. @JohnKormylo. This seems to be in line with what was written by leandriis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your first question, you can use a `\vspace` of your choice. (In the following example, the contents do not fit onto the page any longer due to the space that I intruduced.)

The second part can easily be achieved by using a package that is dedicated to subfigures. In the following example, I use the `subcaption` package and simply replaced all occurences of `minipage` by `subfigure`. Additionally, I have changed the appearence of the subfigure's captions to match your description:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{
    font=bf,
    size=normalsize,
    justification=centerlast,
    }
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{
    font=normal,
    size=normalsize,
    justification=centerlast,
    }
\renewcommand*{\thesubfigure}{Panel \thefigure\Alph{subfigure}:}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\figurewidth}{0.95}
\newcommand{\figureheight}{0.375}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\figurewidth\linewidth, height=\figureheight\textheight]{example-image}
        \caption{The first frog}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\figurewidth\linewidth, height=\figureheight\textheight]{example-image}
        \caption{The second frog}
    \end{subfigure}
     \vspace{1cm}

    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\figurewidth\linewidth, height=\figureheight\textheight]{example-image}
        \caption{The third frog}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\figurewidth\linewidth, height=\figureheight\textheight]{example-image}
        \caption{The fourth frog}
    \end{subfigure}
    \vspace{2ex}
\caption{A couple of frogs}
\parbox{\linewidth}{\small\lipsum[1]\vspace{2ex}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I wanted! Thank you very much, @leandriis.